# Undefined en consulta php

Tags: php, angularjs

No sé por qué, pero me muestra los datos correctamente en una consulta y en la otra me salen los datos `Undefined`!

Mostrando el siguiente error cuando pasa por el proceso del *for* `console.log($scope.servicio):`

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in   **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paneldetencion/app/php/consultaServicios.php** on line **9**
>   Error querying database.

Y cuando muestro solo el *data* `console.log(data):`

> **Notice**:  Undefined property: stdClass::$servicio_id in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Paneldetencion/app/php/consultaServicios.php** on line **9**
>   Error querying database.

Los dos me arrojan a la misma linea la 9: `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");`
La consulta php es esta:

```
<?php  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');    

    date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");    
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mongos')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $id = $request->id;

    $query = "SELECT identificador, nombre FROM Servicios WHERE id =".$id;
    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.', error_reporting());

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = array(
            $row["identificador"]
           $row["nombre"]
        ); 
    }

   echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Y el controlador está así:

```
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/Paneldetencion/app/php/consultaServicios.php',  
     //   url: 'php/consultaServicios.php',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },

        data:{

          id: 38
        }

    })

.then(function(data) {

    var dat = data.data;

    $scope.servicio = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {

            var datos = {
                nombre: dat[i].nombre,
                identificador: dat[i].identificador,
            };

            $scope.servicio.push(datos);
        } 

        console.log("RESPUESTA: ",$scope.servicio)
});
```

Como dije anteriormente, ésta misma consulta la tengo con otros datos y los retorna correctamente, pero no todos los datos por el `id` del where. Pero los muestra. Aquí todos los datos están `Undefined`

Comment: No entiendo bien tu error, donde ocurre en Angular o en PHP?

Comment: es la misma que creaste tú sioesi.. tengo ejecutando dos consultas al mismo tiempo la de la otra vez que sí funciona y esta que muestra los datos undefined!...

Comment: Intente haciendo solo esta consulta y persistia mostrando el error  en esta consulta

Comment: Yo probe el mismo codigo RECIEN que te deje y no tengo ningun problema, el problema que tu adjuntas es cuando lo ejecuto del navegador sin hacerle post...

Comment: pero ejecuta dos consultas a distintas tablas al mismo tiempo, una me funciona y la otra no

Comment: donde estan las dos consultas a distintas tablas Hernan?

Comment: sí en distintas tablas, lo extraño es que me pide un id_usuario cosa que especificamente en esta consulta no uso y no esta declarado en ninguna parte....

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48199/discussion-between-sioesi-and-hernan-humana).

Comment: entra al chat para no llenar de comentarios aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que tu haces

```
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
```

Y `$arr` no esta definida en ningun lado, debe ser con `$array`

**EDIT**

Por lo que vimos en el chat el primer error (despues del que te nombre en esta respuesta) es que tu envías desde `AngularJS` el valor `servicio_id` mientras que en tu archivo `php` estas buscando `id` y esto nunca iba a funcionar. ***Y este error no se puede visualizar en tu pregunta ya que no pusiste el código real de donde se estaba produciendo el error, el código que dejaste funciona perfecto.***

El error fue con tu base de datos después de solucionar la petición `http` desde `AngularJS` cuando te devolvió que uno de tus campos no estaba en la tabla que buscabas. Eso es otro error que creo que va en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esta fila esta demas:
   $request = json_decode($postdata);
Ya que no estas enviando un Json sino un Objec.

Comment: Pense en iliminarla pero utiliza el $postdata y abajo de la misma linea la requiere el $id

Comment: Si borra la linea, recibe `{Object : {id: 1}}` ya que si esta enviando un json desde Angular